# SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am having this issue more than few days now, and it's very frustrating. I am using a MVC web API application which is working on local and dev server, but unfortunately when I wanted it to deploy on the staging server, I badly got stuck with this issue. Below is the code and options I have tried so far:

```
  private HttpResponseMessage ExecutePostRequest(string url, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContent Body = new StringContent(body);
            Body.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Autorization", "Bearer" + "AccessToken");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, Body).Result;
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteLogs(e.ToString(), "Exception");
            throw;
        }

    }
```

URL I am passing is of some public API like (https://api.powerbi.com/beta----)

- Windows Firewall is off
- I used Proxy settings as below but nothing worked :

  ```
   <defaultProxy> <proxy usesystemdefault="true"   proxyaddress="https://api.powerbi.com"   bypassonlocal="True"/> </defaultProxy></system.net>
  ```

The above code gives exception as "The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme."

- I even checked my IE LAN settings. It is not using any proxy settings.
- Below is the Stack Trace

  [SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it]
     System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +996
     System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +75
     System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +480

  [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
     System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +3366493
     System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +155

  [HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]

  [AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
     System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +5863512
     SignalR.Dal.Repositories.DashboardRepository.ExecutePostRequest(String url, String body) +475
     SignalR.Dal.Repositories.DashboardRepository.GetNominations() +1970
     Signal.WebApi.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +359

  [HttpException (0x80004005): One or more errors occurred.]
     System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12600941
     System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
     System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
     System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
     System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

  [HttpException (0x80004005): One or more errors occurred.]
     System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12617988
     System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
     System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12457605

Comment: From the error message, is clear that you can access the API you want to call, so there are no network issues. Is `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Autorization", "Bearer" + "AccessToken");` correct? Based on this code, it will result to `BearerAccessToken` with no space.

Comment: Same code is working on the local and DEV server. What I should use there as its a public API no authentication is required.

Comment: One would expect a space between the 2 words, e.g. `Bearer AccessToken`. But since no authentication is required, why you are adding the `Autorization` header?

Comment: Even after removing that line, I am getting the same error

Comment: Enable networking tracing and see which IP address your app is trying to connect, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing That should give you some hints.

Comment: I know which ip is getting hit and the port aswell

Comment: I had this problem in my DEV environment because my Web API didn't had started, i.e., I had to run it once time and check that in my IIS express that the Web API was up and ready. So, it seems to me that for some reason your Web API is down.